# Creating a conditional column based on consecutive rows with same values in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have researched other questions on a similar issue, but they are either in a different language or create unwanted, unnecessary columns.

I have a `table1`:

```
id        date        value
aaaaa     2021-01-01  true
aaaaa     2021-01-02  true
aaaaa     2021-01-03  false
aaaaa     2021-01-04  false
aaaaa     2021-01-05  false
aaaaa     2021-01-06  true
...
aaaaa     2021-12-31  false
aaaab     2021-01-01  true
...
zzzzz     2021-12-31  false
```

where `id` is a string-type entry, `date` ranges from `2021-01-01` to `2021-12-31`, and `value` is a boolean-type entry, either `true` or `false`. The table is ordered by `date`.

I would like to generate a new table `table2` with **just two columns**, `id` and `passed`.

- `id` is the same column from the `table1`.
- `passed` is also a boolean-type entry. When ordered by `date` in `table1`, if `value` is `false` for **3 consecutive rows** for an `id`, `passed` is `false` for that `id` and otherwise is `true`.

Ideally, `table2` should look like this:

```
id      passed
aaaaa   false
aaaab   true
...
zzzzz   true
```

---

I tried using a subquery such as this:

```
SELECT id,
       value,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER i.date AS time1,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.id, i.value ORDER BY i.date) AS time2
          FROM table1 t
       ) t
GROUP BY id, value, (time1 - time2)

...
```

but it returns an error as it does not recognize the window alias `i.date`. (Not to mention that this query probably wouldn't exactly deliver my desired output yet, as I didn't even put the condition of `value` having to be `false` in 3 consecutive rows.)

Any insight on this question is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like below approach is most simple and straightforward for your case

```
select id, 
  instr(string_agg('' || value, '' order by date), repeat('false', 3)) = 0 as passed
from your_table
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`LAG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) to get the values of the previous 2 rows (partition the data by id and sort it by date) and then compare if all 3 are the same.
`MAX` will return `true` if any of the column values is `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Using your data:

```sql
WITH your_table AS
(
  SELECT 'aaaaa' AS id, DATE('2021-01-01') AS date, true AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-01-02'), true UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-01-03'), false UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-01-04'), false UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-01-05'), false UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-01-06'), true UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaaa', DATE('2021-12-31'), false UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaab', DATE('2021-01-01'), true UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzzzz', DATE('2021-12-31'), false
)

SELECT
  id,
  MAX(value = value_p AND value = value_p2) AS passed
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    date,
    value,
    LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS value_p,
    LAG(value, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS value_p2
  FROM your_table
)
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two row_numbers could solve the problem, try it as the following:

```
Select Distinct id,
       Case 
         When Max(Case When Not Value Then t_f_cnt End) Over (Partition By id) >=3 
         Then False Else True
       End As Pass
From
(
   Select *, COUNT(*) Over (Partition By id, grp) As t_f_cnt
   From
   (
     Select *,
      ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By id Order By date) -
      ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By id, value Order By date) As grp
     From table_name
   ) T
) D
Order By id
```

Results according to your input data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below as well.

```sql
SELECT id, MIN(flag) OR COUNT(1) < 3 AS passed FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(value, 1, true) OVER w OR value OR LEAD(value, 1, true) OVER w AS flag
    FROM table1
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)
) GROUP BY 1;
```

> *if `value` is **false** for 3 consecutive rows, `passed` is **false** for that id*

- `A OR B OR C` is false only when they are all `false`.
- `A` : previous row (LAG), `B` : current row, `C` : following row (LEAD)